# Название Темы Вордпресс

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите пожалуйста, как называется дизайн/шаблон, когда сайдбар прилеплен к краю страницы. Мне нужно найти похожие темы, но не знаю как их искать из за того что не знаю как это называется. Не могу применить фильтры поиска. Смотрите скриншот. При этом сайдбар должен быть зафиксирован. Как называется это?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

> Как называется это?

Наверное "фиксированный сайдбар". Но по таким признакам найти  тему практически не реально. Или смотреть по скринам и демкам на оф сайтах производителей или зафиксировать в любой другой теме самостоятельно. Ну, ок, почти в любой теме :)

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, но думал что есть какое-то конкретное название для этого.

Comment: Берите любую понравившуюся тему и делайте фиксированное меню самостоятельно, как вам нужно, как захотите.  Или вы можете выбрать тему с меню и зафиксировать его position:fixed